# xargs doesn't recognize bash aliases

Tags: command-line, xargs, bash

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
find . -iname '.#*' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 foobar
```

where "foobar" is an alias or function defined in my .bashrc file (in my case, it's a function that takes one parameter).  Apparently xargs doesn't recognize these as things it can run.  Is there a clever way to remedy this?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I create scripts on my ~/bin folder instead of creating bash aliases. This way, I can use my aliases from any shell: BASH, ZSH, IPYTHON or FISH.

Comment: Here's a similar (though not identical) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979453/how-can-i-use-aliased-commands-with-xargs

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since only your interactive shell knows about aliases, why not just run the alias without forking out through `xargs`?

```
find . -iname '.#*' -print0 | while read -r -d '' i; do foobar "$i"; done
```

If you're sure that your filenames don't have newlines in them (ick, why would they?), you can simplify this to

```
find . -iname '.#*' -print | while read -r i; do foobar "$i"; done
```

or even just `find -iname '.#*' | ...`, since the default directory is `.` and the default action is `-print`.

One more alternative:

```
 IFS=$'\n'; for i in `find -iname '.#*'`; do foobar "$i"; done
```

telling Bash that words are only split on newlines (default: `IFS=$' \t\n'`).  You should be careful with this, though; some scripts don't cope well with a changed `$IFS`.

Comment: This answer is answering WHY we can't use xargs and HOW we could use xargs with the alias.

Comment: This answer gives us *alternatives* to using xargs.  For an answer that works *using xargs*, see @camh's answer in the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979453/how-can-i-use-aliased-commands-with-xargs (which Nathan Fellman linked to up above)

Comment: xargs can use paralell mode, so that while is not suitable

Comment: The default path of `find` is `.` for GNU find but not for BSD find ([FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)), [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/find.1), [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/find.1), [macOS](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/find.1.html)), which are conform to [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) in that respect.

Comment: I get the following errors:
while: Expression Syntax.
i: Undefined variable.

I tried the other solution of making an alias for xargs as 'xargs ' with no luck.

I'm using an alias to a script which will take many arguments and open them all in sublime-text.

Answer (score 16):

Adding a trailing space to the command being aliased causes other aliased commands to expand:

```
alias xargs='xargs ' # aliased commands passed to xargs will be expanded
```

See this answer for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59842439/11873710

Comment: I think this is now appreciated enough.

Comment: I already had an alias for `xargs` as just `x`, so adding the trailign space was perfect!

Answer (score 13):

Using Bash you may also specify the number of args being passed to your alias (or function) like so:

```
alias myFuncOrAlias='echo'  # alias defined in your ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, ...
echo arg1 arg2 | xargs -n 1 bash -cil 'myFuncOrAlias "$1"' arg0
echo arg1 arg2 | xargs  bash -cil 'myFuncOrAlias "$@"' arg0
```

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't work because `xargs` expects to be able to `exec` the *program* given as its parameter.

Since `foobar` in your case is just a `bash` alias or function there's no program to execute.

Although it involves starting `bash` for each file returned by `find`, you could write a small shell script thus:

```
#!/bin/bash
. $(HOME)/.bashrc
func $*
```

and then pass the name of that script as the parameter to `xargs`

Comment: Where should I place that script so that *it* is recognized by `xargs`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin wherever you want, so long as it's either in `$PATH` or give it's location directly to `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use find like this:

```
find . -iname '' -exec cmd '{}' \;
```

'{}' will get replaced with the filename, and \; is necessary to terminate the execution chain. However, if that doesn't work with your function, you might need to run it through bash:

```
find .. |sed -e "s/.*/cmd '&'/"|bash
```

Find prints each file on a line, sed just prefixes this with your command, and then pipe it to bash for execution. Skip the |bash first to see what will happen.

Comment: If you're using a newish GNU find, use `-exec cmd '{}' +` instead: this acts more like xargs in that it will batch arguments together into one run instead of exec'ing a new cmd for every file found.

Comment: I rather think if his function was capable of taking multiple parameters he wouldn't be supplying the -L 1 options to xargs...

Comment: Oh, that's what -L does?  I didn't look it up, and I use -n for that purpose.

Comment: Sadly, these methods still don't work with aliases and functions. Probably because .bashrc only gets invoked for interactive shells. But the first one IS a neat trick.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
find . -iname '.#*' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 $(foobar)
```