# How can I use aliased commands with xargs?

Tags: linux, tcsh, xargs

I have the following alias in my .aliases:

```
alias gi grep -i
```

and I want to look for `foo` case-insensitively in all the files that have the string `bar` in their name:

```
find -name \*bar\* | xargs gi foo
```

This is what I get:

```
xargs: gi: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to use aliases in xargs, or do I have to use the full version:

```
   find -name \*bar\* | xargs grep -i foo
```

**Note:**  This is a simple example.  Besides `gi` I have some pretty complicated aliases that I can't expand manually so easily.

**Edit:**  I used `tcsh`, so please specify if an answer is shell-specific.

Comment: Here's a similar (though not identical) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513611/xargs-doesnt-recognize-bash-aliases

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Aliases are shell-specific - in this case, most likely bash-specific. To execute an alias, you need to execute bash, but aliases are only loaded for interactive shells (more precisely, `.bashrc` will only be read for an interactive shell).

**bash -i** runs an interactive shell (and sources .bashrc).
**bash -c *cmd*** runs *cmd*.

Put them together:
**bash -ic *cmd*** runs *cmd* in an interactive shell, where *cmd* can be a bash function/alias defined in your `.bashrc`.

```
find -name \*bar\* | xargs bash -ic gi foo
```

should do what you want.

Edit: I see you've tagged the question as "tcsh", so the bash-specific solution is not applicable. With tcsh, you dont need the `-i`, as it appears to read .tcshrc unless you give `-f`.

Try this:

```
find -name \*bar\* | xargs tcsh -c gi foo
```

It worked for my basic testing.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40912257/5353461) if you want to behave nicely with files including whitespace.

Answer (score 13):

This solution worked perfect for me in bash:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244516/365245

**Problem**

```
[~]: alias grep='grep -i'
[~]: find -maxdepth 1 -name ".bashrc" | xargs grep name      # grep alias not expanded
[~]: ### no matches found ###
```

**Solution**

```
[~]: alias xargs='xargs ' # create an xargs alias with trailing space
[~]: find -maxdepth 1 -name ".bashrc" | xargs grep name     # grep alias gets expanded
# Name     : .bashrc
```

**Why it works**

```
[~]: man alias  
alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]  
(snip)  
A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
alias substitution when the alias is expanded.
```

Comment: It does not work if  we use  find  -print0 | xargs -0  grep

Answer (score 8):

Turn "gi" into a script instead

eg, in `/home/$USER/bin/gi`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/grep -i "$@"
```

don't forget to mark the file executable.

Answer (score 7):

The suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513611/xargs-doesnt-recognize-bash-aliases) is to avoid xargs and use a "while read" loop instead of xargs:

```
find -name \*bar\* | while read file; do gi foo "$file"; done
```

See the accepted answer in the link above for refinements to deal with spaces or newlines in filenames.

Comment: If file names have blanks or newlines in them, this is not as good as xargs with -0 option (and find with -print0).

Answer (score 2):

This is special-character safe:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 bash -ic 'gi foo "$@"' --
```

The `-print0` and `-0` use `\0` or `NUL`-terminated strings so you don't get weird things happening when filenames have spaces in them.

`bash` sets the first argument after the command string as `$0`, so we pass it a dummy argument (`--`) so that the first file listed by `find` doesn't get consumed by `$0`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution in you case would be to expand your alias inline. But that is valid for csh/tcsh only.

```
find -name \*bar\* | xargs `alias gi` foo
```

for bash it will be more tricky, not so handy but still might be useful:

```
find -name \*bar\* | xargs `alias gi | cut -d "'" -f2` foo
```

Answer (score 0):

For tcsh (which does not have functions), you could use:

```
gi foo `find -name "*bar*"`
```

For bash/ksh/sh, you can create a function in the shell.

```
   function foobar 
   {
      gi $1 `find . -type f -name "*"$2"*"`
   }

   foobar foo bar
```

Remember that using backquotes in the shell is more advantageous than using xargs from multiple perspectives. Place the function in your .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash you may also specify the number of args being passed to your alias (or function) like so:

```
alias myFuncOrAlias='echo'  # alias defined in your ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, ...
echo arg1 arg2 | xargs -n 1 bash -cil 'myFuncOrAlias "$1"' arg0
```

(should work for tcsh in a similar way)

```
# alias definition in ~/.tcshrc
echo arg1 arg2 | xargs -n 1 tcsh -cim 'myFuncOrAlias "$1"' arg0  # untested
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many solutions with `xargs` that didn't work for me, went for an alternative with a loop, see examples below:

```
for file in $(git ls-files *.txt); do win2unix $file; done
for file in $(find . -name *.txt); do win2unix $file; done
```

Put your expression that generates a list of files inside `$()` as in the examples above. I've used `win2unix` which is a function in my *.bashrc* that takes a file path and converts it to Linux endings. Would expect aliases to also work.

Note that I did not have spaces in my paths or filenames.