# ct lsco -a -s -cview | xargs ct ci -nc (Clearcase multiple files check-in)

Tags: clearcase, xargs

I get error while running this command on linux.

```
ct lsco -a -s -cview | xargs ct ci -nc
```

(`ct` is for `cleartool`)

```
xargs: ct: No such file or directory
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the alias '`ct`' with `xargs`.

Use `cleartool`.

As explained in "[`xargs` doesn't recognize bash aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513638/6309)":

> This doesn't work because `xargs` expects to be able to `exec` the program given as its parameter.
>
> Since `ct` in your case is just a bash alias or function there's no program to execute.

More details in "[How can I use aliased commands with `xargs`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979657/6309)".