# How to diff all modifications of all checkout files under a directory recursively with Clearcase?

Tags: recursion, diff, clearcase

I'm using ClearCase. I checked out several files under a directory, some of files in its sub-directory, some in sub-sub-directory.

What I want is to list the diff of all my modifications on these checked out files under this certain directory recursively.

What I currently do is:

```
for file in $(cleartool lsco -recurse -me -cview -fmt "%n\n"); do 
    cleartool diff -serial_format -pred $file; 
done
```

I use a bash for loop, but I perhaps it can be done with a simple ClearCase command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP suggests using the [list of checked out files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3094806/6309), but there is no way to find the diff in one cleartool command.
An `xargs` ([used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16732238/6309)) might be easier

```
cleartool lsco -recurse -me -cview -fmt "%n\n" | xargs -n 1 cleartool diff -serial_format -pred
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there seems to be some issues. Clearcase diff doesn't have a -nc options, maybe it's a version issue? and diff asks for at least two objects to compare.

Comment: @user3093552 I have fixed the find command, and suggested an alternative to the bash loop.

Comment: Thanks again. For the find case, I got some errors like:`cleartool: Error: Unable to access "./ncs_trace.h@@": Is a directory.` 

For the xargs, seems the trailing `$file` should be removed. While even with it removed, as I tested, it dumped many lines which are far more than my modifications, don't know why.

Comment: @user3093552 I have limited the find to files only (not directories). And I have removed the `$file` (typo)

Comment: for the find case, I still got the errors like:`cleartool: Error: Unable to access "./ncs_trace.h@@": Is a directory.`, even with `-type f`; for the xargs case, it diff all the files together,like this:

`********************************
<<< file 1: /nec01_core/cmw/noss/src/ncbmain.c@@/main/vz_int_rl50/dev_rh45_tomix_sdm/0
>>> file 2: ncbmain.c
>>> file 3: necqueue.c
********************************
`

Comment: @user3093552 regarding xargs, I found more ideas in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013788115: I have edited the answer to use `xargs -n 1` and add the final `"{}"` as a placeholder for the xargs argument.

Comment: For xargs, with the trailing `{}`, I got this `cleartool: Error: Pathname not found: "{}".`. Remove `{}` and preserve the `-n 1`, it works. As for the find case, if we cannot find out the cause, I think we'd better remove it then close this question.

Comment: @user3093552 ok, I have edited the xargs option, and removed the fnid option.