# Piping filenames from grep to function

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm working with a simple function that outputs some useful information about jobs I run on a cluster.  It's called report:

```
function report()
{
   for FILE in $*;
      do tac $FILE | grep best -m1;
   done;
}
```

I want to call report on the output files I generate, but only when something goes wrong and the job is terminated.  The output file will have `Terminated` as the last line.  So, for instance:

```
[XXXXXX@login-0-0 scripts]$ grep Term optim_HGF.o1910512 -n
242:Terminated

[XXXXXX@login-0-0 scripts]$ report optim_HGF.o1910512
New best fit at function call 4496.  Took 6.292452e+00 seconds. Objective = 4.129260e-01
```

Now I try to use grep to find the files for which something went wrong and pipe the names to report.

```
[XXXXXX@login-0-0 scripts]$ grep optim_HGF.o* -l | report
```

But this gives no output.  How can I accomplish what I'm aiming to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're missing is `xargs`:

```
grep -l Term optim_HGF.o* | xargs report
```

Comment: One catch though, report here is an aliased function and not a command, so the subshell that xargs generates is unaware of it.  Your answer put me on the track to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513611/xargs-doesnt-recognize-bash-aliases that ended up meeting my needs.  Thanks!